# Bash: getting all lines in a file matching with a string or another one (and keeping the order)

Tags: bash

I have a text file and its content is something like this ("..." means "more text"):

```
input file path/to/file1.txt
...
...
result ....
...
input file path/to/file2.txt
...
...
result ....
...
input file path/to/file3.txt
...
...
result ....
...
```

I would like to filter the lines starting from `input file` and `result` keeping the original order of appearance. 
EDIT: But the `input file` is an absolute path to the input file... So I would like to filter that part but getting only the last part of the path (I mean the filename in itself)

The desired result should be:

```
input file file1.txt
result ....
input file file2.txt
result ....
input file file3.txt
result ....
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ grep -E '^(input file|result)' inputFile > outFile
$ cat outFile
input file ...
result ....
input file ...
result ....
input file ...
result ....
```

If you want to filter out lines that don't have these, put `-v` option.

```
$ grep -Ev '^(input file|result)' inputFIle
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
```

If `path/to` is a fixed path for all `file*.txt`, then you can use this `sed` command to print your desired result

```
$ sed -e 's|path/to/||g' -nE -e '/^(input|result)/p' inputFile
input file file1.txt
result ....
input file file2.txt
result ....
input file file3.txt
result ....
```

Comment: That works, but I had to add a modification

Comment: For the modification you've posted, this solution should work as well.

Comment: yes, sorry, I forgot to delete `path/to/` in the desired result...

Comment: See my updated answer